# How can I fix this "Expected an indented block" error?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn to define a function in Python.

I tried this syntax

```
>>> def hello():
... print("Hello")
```

but when I press the enter key after "Hello" I get the `expected an indented block` error.

Actually I am trying to write this code

```
>>> def hello():
... print("Hello")
... print("Computers are Fun")
```

but I cannot because of the error message.

What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Check your indentation. Unlike C, Java, C++, there are no {} to enclose a function, code segment. Indentation is what defines a code section, loop, function etc.

```
>>> def hello():
...     print "hello"
...
>>> hello()
hello
>>>
```

Note the indentation from the def line and print line. Your code is missing correct formatting.

Comment: I think this is the most clear answer, but I upvoted everyone, because we're all saying the same (correct) thing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to indent (4 spaces [recommended](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)) the commands that go in a function, like this:

```
>>> def hello():
...     print 'hello'
... 
>>> hello()
hello
```

Comment: @WaleedKhan for sure; I was just following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Comment: @WaleedKhan: 1 space is also acceptable, as is 2 spaces, 5 spaces, 3 tabs, or a complex interleaving of 47 tabs and 79 spaces, so long as you're consistent. Introducing 4 spaces as the standard is still a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly format your functions. Python has very specific spacing requirements.

```
def hello():
    print "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

´expected an Indented block´ means that your indentation is not correct, try following code:

```
def hello():
    print "Hello"

def hello2():
    print "Hello"
    print "Computers are Fun"

hello()
hello2()
```